# mongodb the MongoWaitQueueFullException

Tags: mongodb

What's wrong about this?

mongodb3.01 x64 + win8.1 64 + CSharpDriver-2.0.0-rc0

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoWaitQueueFullException Message: 
“MongoDB.Driver.MongoWaitQueueFullException”类型的未经处理的异常在 mscorlib.dll 中发生

其他信息: The wait queue for acquiring a connection to server localhost:27017 is full.
```

Would you meet the  exception and how to prevent it?

Comment: Due to the Kanji  in your error log it is more difficult to understand some part of the error message, I did a quick searchand found this [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1180)

Answer (score 13):

You application exceeded limit of opened connections.
Default connection pool size is 100.

You can set pool size on creating MongoClient

```
new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/?maxPoolSize=555");
```

or

```
new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings { MaxConnectionPoolSize = 555, Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost") });
```

Comment: Does incresing number of connection can have some negative effects?

Comment: @AleksanderBethke There are no direct negative effects. But it's time to answer some questions: 1) why does app need to have 100 simultaneously open connections? 2) does app reuse connections (no memory leaks and lost references) ? 3) there are limitations on OS level which you cannot exceed.